# File handling using servlet

Tags: gwt, servlets

Can we write file handling code inside a servlet class in java based web application, if yes then where should i create that file and how can i maintain synchronization between multiple file writes???

Comment: In servlet, it is just like writing a local app because it is on server side.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we write file handling code inside a servlet class in java based web application?

Yes, you can create and manipulate files(located on your server) like any typical servlet in your java web application.

> where should i create that file?

You have to do file manipulation operation in your `***ServiceImpl.java` file which located in `*.*.*.server` package.

> how can i maintain synchronization between multiple file writes?

Servlets are not thread safe ([Servlet Specification JSR-315](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=315)) and you have to synchronize your code manually, an alternative is to implement the `SingleThreadModel` interface which requires the container to guarantee that there is only one request thread at a time in the service method.